# Portable Class Library target frameworks

Tags: .net, visual-studio, portable-class-library

When creating a Portable Class Library, the option to select target frameworks is shown (as below).

[image]

What is a target framework (other than an item in the list)?

I'm not asking from a high-level, abstract, perspective. There is plenty of documentation available for that. Specifically, what does it mean to create a target framework?  Does it require providing implementations of the System DLL's (mscorlib, System.Core, etc)?

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx#change_targets):

> When you change the targets, the APIs that are available to you for developing your project will change to match your selection.

Does this mean Visual Studio compares the implementation of the DLL's provided by each targeted framework, and warns if you attempt to access functionality not provided by all?

If I wanted to create a new target framework, how would I go about it? What would I have to install, and where?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean Visual Studio compares the implementation of the DLL's provided by each targeted framework, and warns if you attempt to access functionality not provided by all?

Not quite. We have a heuristic that tries to find the best profile based on the selection you made. It doesn't look at the APIs but at the set of platforms it supports.

> If I wanted to create a new target framework, how would I go about it? What would I have to install, and where?

That would be hard, if not impossible, as we currently don't support this. In fact, they way we generate the profile assumes knowing the state of all target platforms.

Why do you want to create your own TF? Can you explain what your trying achieve? Maybe there is an alternative.